# Download/Export files with MacGap

Tags: javascript, xcode, macgap

I am working on a simple text editor that generates and exports files in Markdown, txt, HTML and PDF. This functionality is working like a charm already in the browser. But when it comes to 'app' I am building with [MacGap](https://macgapproject.github.io/documentation/), it doesn't work as expected, instead of downloading the files, it prints them in the same window or doesn't do anything (in the case of PDF).

MacGap has a way to handle write/read files as it [is explained here](https://macgapproject.github.io/documentation/ref/file.html) but I am struggling with making it work with javascript.

Here is my code to export the text files:

```js
// Print //

function printPDF() {
    const printContent = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
    window.print();

}

// Export TXT, MD, HTML //

function downloadContent(type) {
    let editorContent = ''
    if (type === 'txt') {
        editorContent = document.getElementById('content').textContent;
        
    } else if(type === 'md') {
        const turndownService = new TurndownService({ headingStyle: 'atx', codeBlockStyle: 'fenced', emDelimiter: '*' });
        editorContent = turndownService.turndown(document.getElementById('content').innerHTML);
    } else {
        editorContent =`
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <title>HTML Title</title>
        </head>
            <body>
                ${document.getElementById('content').innerHTML}
            </body>
        </html>
        `
    }

    const linkElement = document.createElement("a")
    linkElement.setAttribute("download", `filename.${type}`)
    linkElement.setAttribute("href", 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(editorContent))
    linkElement.click()

    document.body.removeChild(linkElement);
    
}
```

And here is my try to make it work with Macgap based on their documentation (example):

```
 MacGap.File.write('txt', 'content', 'string');
 MacGap.File.write('md', 'content', 'string');
```

But I don't think this is how it works.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: MacGap is a great tool but it is a bit obsolete since it is built using objective-C. Those options are the only ones supported by MacGap, so file management is not possible.
I ended up building and packaging my app with Electron js. Still the difference in size is insane, but it was the best solution.

MacGap app: 3.6MB

Electron js: 180.5MB

Same app. But, it is ok, hopefully the electron team manages to reduce the size in the future.